# Single infix like method invocation with Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala the dot notation is in much cases optional, like `1 + 2` equals `1.+(2)`.

But is it also possible, with some magic, to write also things like:

```
object u {
  def meth (s: String) = println(s)
  meth "str"  // as shortcut for meth("str")
}
```

Result:

```
<console>:3: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
```

But this would be very interesting for creating internal DSLs, if something like this works. *Note*: In this hypothetical question I'll don't want to draw on things like `u meth "str"`.

Comment: If it's possible to write something like `meth "str` without calling on a object. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar using string interpolation from Scala 2.10, but I don't think you should:

```
scala> implicit class Meth(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
     |   def meth(): String = "meth" + sc.parts(0)
     | }
defined class Meth

scala> meth"str"
res0: String = methstr
```

It isn't possible to use expressions like `meth "str"` in Scala. You can write `u meth "str"`, `"str" meth`, `meth"str"` or `meth ("str")`, but not `meth "str"`.

Comment: Ok, too bad. Thanks anyway! :)